# MLKit unable to detect text on Android-8

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, ocr, google-mlkit

I am trying `com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition` library for OCR which is working absolutely fine on all Android versions except Android-8.

The library `play-services-mlkit-text-recognition` is able to recognise text on all Android versions but it fails to recognise text on Android-8 and returning empty array.

I followed all the steps given in https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android.

The library I am using is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2` with Google Play Services (`com.google.android.gms`) version `22.50.14 (version code: 225014021)`.

Does anyone have any idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried after updating the Google Play services to latest (23.13.12) and it worked!

I don't see any documentation of minimum version of Google Play Services required for MLKit.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you got it working. If you had any logs of the issue to share, it would be helpful to figure out why.

Thx!